# A wave equation with a weird boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

${ u }_{ tt }-{ c }^{ 2 }{ u }_{ xx }=0 ,\  0<x<\infty ,\ 0\le t <\infty $

Initial conditions: $u(x,0)=0\ $ and ${u}_{t}(x,0)=V$ where $V$ is a positive constant.

Boundary condition: ${u}_{t}(0,t)+a{u}_{x}(0,t)=0$ where $a$ is a constant and $a>c>0$.

I am trying to solve this problem.

My attempt: $ u=f(x+ct)+g(x-ct) $ for some functions  $\ f\  and\ g   $.

But the problem is that I cannot find a solution that satisfies all the conditions simultaneously. Somebody help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a solution defined in the region $D=\{(x,t):x\ge0,\ t\ge0\}$. If $(x,t)\in D$, then $x+c\,t\ge0$, while $x-c\,t$ can be positive or negative. From the initial conditions you can find in the usual way the values of $f$ and $g$ on $[x,\infty)$:
$$
f(x)=\frac{V}{2\,c}\,x,\quad g(x)=-\frac{V}{2\,c}\,x,\qquad x\ge0.
$$
Then
$$
u(x,t)=V\,t\qquad x\in D,\quad x-c\,t\ge0.
$$
In order to define the solution on the region $\{(x,t)\in D:x-c\,t<0\}$ we need to extend $g$ to $(-\infty,0)$. For this we use the boundary condition:
$$
u_t(0,t)+a\,u_x(0,t)=(c+a)f'(c\,t)+(a-c)g'(-c\,t)=0.
$$
From here we obtain that if $x<0$ then
$$
g'(x)=-\frac{a+c}{a-c}\,f'(-x)=-\frac{a+c}{a-c}\,\frac{V}{2\,c}.
$$
I hope you can finish now.

Comment: Thx sir. Now I see the core part is the case of $x<ct$!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is linear.

Let say $U$ is the global solution. If you have a solution $U_1$ satisfying only the boundary condition. Then you should look for $U_2 = U-U_1$. $U_2$ is subject to homogeneous boundary condition. U2 can be called the asymptotic solution while U1 is the transient one and depends on the initial condition.

Otherwise, Laplace transform in $x$ and $t$ would probably do the job.

Variable separation may also be useful : $u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$

Comment: I am afraid we cannot split it further because only one condition is nontrivial, i.e., $ {u}_{t}(x,0)=V$.

Comment: Solving the homogeneous problem may be a first step (case $V=0$)
Laplace transform in $x$ and $t$ will probably do the job for both the homogeneous problem and the inhomogeneous one. EDIT : Your BC are perfect for Laplace transform in time, leading to a simple ODE in $x$